# How to scale down a widget to display an overview in a grid view?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, the user can create and edit multiple pages that are displayed in a PageView. The user can see one page at a time. Now I want to show an overview of all pages by shrinking the widgets and showing them in a Wrap layout widget.

I've tried this with the Transform.scale widget, but this keeps the original size of the page and just displays the child widget at a lower scale.Therefore this does not bring the desired effect in a wrap layout.